# numpy - apply_along_axis function

Tags: python, numpy

if i have the following array:

```
b = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
```

and I run the follwing function:

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, 1, b)
```

I get this:

```
[[[1 0 0]
  [0 2 0]
  [0 0 3]]

 [[4 0 0]
  [0 5 0]
  [0 0 6]]

 [[7 0 0]
  [0 8 0]
  [0 0 9]]]
```

but for:

```
 np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, 0, b)
```

I get this:

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [4 5 6]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [7 8 9]]]
```

I though that the output will be:

```
[[[1 0 0]
  [0 4 0]
  [0 0 7]]

 [[2 0 0]
  [0 5 0]
  [0 0 8]]

 [[3 0 0]
  [0 6 0]
  [0 0 9]]]
```

Thank you

What should I do instead?

Comment: What if `b` was (2,3) shape.  One axis case will be (2,3,3), but the other (2,2,3)?  When the func expands the dimensions, the mapping from `b` to result won't be obvious.  Read the apply code for yourself!

Comment: @hpaulj Personally, I think it's a good question. It is relevant to the last example of [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html). The doc says 'For a function that returns a higher dimensional array, those dimensions are inserted in place of the axis dimension.', but I don't quite understand how this works. Since the shape of intermediate value of `np.apply_along_axis(print, 0/1, b)` is the same. So the `np.diag` for intermediate value will be the same shape. But the dimension difference causes the different logic of output.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, are you imagining that `apply` is simply `np.array([np.diag(b[i,:]) for i in range(b.shape[1])]`?   I tried to illustrate what `apply` is doing with array that don't simply return (3,3,3).

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, there isn't a difference in 'logic'.  The actual is a transpose of the expected.  Personally I don't like `apply`.  It's not a speed tool, and only makes iteration on 3d+ arrays simpler.  On 2d arrays it doesn't help, and as noted here, the logic can be hard to follow.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, I added your `print` to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an argument with different shapes, and a function that adds a size 1 dimension.

```
In [237]: b= np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

In [238]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x[:,None], 1,b)
Out[238]: 
array([[[0],
        [1],
        [2]],

       [[3],
        [4],
        [5]]])
```

The result is (2,3,1).  It iterated on axis 0, passing `b[i,:]` to the function.

But with the other axis:

```
In [239]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x[:,None], 0,b)
Out[239]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2]],

       [[3, 4, 5]]])
```

the result is (2,1,3)

It iterated on axis 1, passing `b[i,:]` to the function.  The (2,1) results are kept together, with the iteration axis still last.

As for my comment, `diag` expands the (2,3) to (2,2,3)

```
In [241]: np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, 0,b)
Out[241]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

I suspect you imagine that `apply` does this kind of iteration and result construction:

```
In [248]: np.array([np.diag(b[:,i]) for i in range(b.shape[1])])
Out[248]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 3]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 4]],

       [[2, 0],
        [0, 5]]])
```

That's a (3,2,2).  But the size 3 dimension has moved from the end to the start.  That' not a 'mapping' of the (2,3) `b`.

`np.array([np.diag(b[i,:]) for i in range(b.shape[0])])` produces (2,3,3), matching `np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, 1,b)`

`apply` behaves more like:

```
In [250]: np.stack([np.diag(b[:,i]) for i in range(b.shape[1])], axis=2)
Out[250]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

In gory detail, `apply` is doing something close to:

```
In [251]: trial = np.diag(b[:,0]).shape; trial
Out[251]: (2, 2)    
In [253]: res = np.zeros(trial+(b.shape[1],), int); res.shape
Out[253]: (2, 2, 3)    
In [254]: for i in range(b.shape[1]):
     ...:     res[...,i] = np.diag(b[:,i])   
In [255]: res
Out[255]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

Oh, and `apply` is no faster than this iteration.

In trying to understand `apply` it can be helpful to display the arrays being passed to the function:

```
In [257]: np.apply_along_axis(print,0,b)
[0 3]
[1 4]
[2 5]
Out[257]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)

In [258]: np.apply_along_axis(print,1,b)
[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
Out[258]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
```

The result is (3,) and (2,) the size of the iteration dimension, and values are `None`, since that's what `print(...)` returns.

Comment: I went to sleep at that time. I draw a [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrabB.png) to show the confusing part. The confusing part is that how the intermediate value of `np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, 0, b)` goes to the result. The doc says 'those dimensions are inserted in place of the axis dimension', but it's hard for me to understand. The different input shape helps understand [what map does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2yoJ.png) and your glory detail explains [how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSY1W.png) the intermediate value are concated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can test your understanding by trying: `np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, 1,np.ones((2,3,4))).shape`.

Answer (score 0):

Just transpose b

```
b = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
c = np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, 1, np.transpose(b))
print(c)
```

```
[[[1 0 0]
  [0 4 0]
  [0 0 7]]

 [[2 0 0]
  [0 5 0]
  [0 0 8]]

 [[3 0 0]
  [0 6 0]
  [0 0 9]]]
```